# How to calculate what percentage a fraction is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have the following:

```
X/.9125
```

I want to turn this into X * Y where Y equals a percentage.

So for example,

500/.9125 = 547.95 rounded.

I would like to instead of dividing 500 by .9125, do

```
500 * Y% = 547.95
```

This for a website where enter number X and multiple it by a percentage like 8%. I want convert the X/.9125 into a equivalent percentage value.

I know I would start with:

```
500/.9125 = 547.95 * P
```

And the multiple both sides by .9125:

```
500 = (547.95 * P) * .9125
```

But then I am not thinking clearly from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, compute $Y\,\% = 100\,\%/.9125 \approx 109.589\,\%$.

Answer (score 1):

When you were at this point $$500 * Y\% = 547.95$$
your next step should have been $$Y\%=\frac{547.95}{500}$$ and you would get your percentage you are after.